# How to get DLL file's function argument and return type?

Tags: dll, dllexport, dlltool

How can we get DLL file's export function list with argument and return type? I don't know in which language DLL is build. I tried all tools regarding DLL, but no tool is giving specifc list with argument and return type.

Comment: You can't get it from just a DLL file (for `stdcall` convention on x86 you can get a stack space size of arguments, which would *usually* be 4*(number of arguments), but that's all). Ah, and when it happens to be in `c++` and mangled names are exported, you can get much of what you want by demangling the names.

Comment: Mangling and demangling is too much long process for more than one DLL, so what is the other solution?

Comment: There is no real solution. If it's *your own* DLL (as you seem to be saying that you can control whether mangling happens), just publish appropriate header files or some other form of interface description. (And for generic case of "I don't know in which language...", the idea makes no sense. What's the use of a number and type of arguments when you don't know calling conventions and what do these types mean?)

Comment: "I don't know in which language..." this is the case that if i want to use any existing functionality of an application and that application have DLL file, then how can i?

Comment: DLL file alone is just *not enough for it*, some interface description is required (you might be able to reverse-engineer the interface, guessing things like "what arguments would make sense here")

Comment: That means without description and documentation i can not. Is there any tool which provide such functionality that it displays all function list with arguments and return type?

Comment: For mangled C++ names, you can list exports with something like `pedump` and then apply a demangler (like `c++filt` for `gcc/g++`, don't know the equivalent for `msvc++`). Exporting `c++` interfaces is not a common practice, though, and if there is no mangled names, you're out of luck (the info about arguments and return type is simply *not there*).